# Laravel : Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have the following in my livewire file to **create a contact and create an new entreprise for him**.

```
    public $contact;
    public $entreprise;

 public function saveContact()
{
    $this->validate();

    $newentreprise = Entreprise::create([            
        'nom' => $this->entreprise['nom'],
        'adresse' => '1',
        'cle' => Str::random(32),
        'code_postal' => '95959', 
        'ville' => 'meknes', 
    ]);

    Contact::create([
        'nom' => $this->contact['nom'],
        'prenom' => $this->contact['prenom'],
        'e_mail' => $this->contact['e_mail'], 
        'cle' => Str::random(32), 
        'telephone_mobile' => '',
        'telephone_fixe' => '',
        'entreprise_id' => $newentreprise->id,
    ]);

    $this->confirmingContactAdd = false ;

}
```

The contact is perfectly created, but I have a problem in the creation of the entreprise. It seems like the input of `'nom'` in `$newentreprise` is not requested correctly. Where do I have the problem ?

**contact.blade.php** of displaying the inputs ( The 3 inputs of contact are requested correctly ) :

```
    <div class="flex mt-6">
<div class="flex-1 text-left  mr-2"><div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
    <x-jet-label class="font-bold" for="prenom" value="{{ __('Prénom') }}" />
    <x-jet-input id="prenom" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="contact.prenom"   />
    <x-jet-input-error for="contact.prenom" class="mt-2" />
</div></div>


<div class="flex-1 text-left  ml-2"><div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
    <x-jet-label class="font-bold" for="nom" value="{{ __('Nom') }}" />
    <x-jet-input id="nom" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="contact.nom"   />
    <x-jet-input-error for="contact.nom" class="mt-2" />
</div></div>


    </div>
    <div class="flex-1 text-left mt-4"><div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
    <x-jet-label class="font-bold" for="e-mail" value="{{ __('E-mail') }}" />
    <x-jet-input id="e-mail" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="contact.e_mail"  />
    <x-jet-input-error for="contact.e_mail" class="mt-2" />
</div></div>


<div class="flex-1 text-left mt-4"><div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
    <x-jet-label class="font-bold" for="entreprise" value="{{ __('Entreprise') }}" />
    <x-jet-input id="entreprise" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="contact.entreprise.nom"  />
    <x-jet-input-error for="contact.entreprise.nom" class="mt-2" />
</div></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing ```contact.entreprise.nom``` to  ```entreprise.nom```

Comment: @Rajesh Paudel Hah it's working :D Thank you very much man !  I really struggled with it..

Comment: No problem. Happens sometime. Happy coding :D